# Inner join combined with where not working

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL code:

```
SELECT community.comment, members.Name, members.Picture
FROM community 
WHERE community.ideaid=1
INNER JOIN members
ON community.userid=members.Memberid
GROUP BY community.userid
```

What I have is two tables, community, and members. I want to get the comment field from community table, and retrieve the user information related to each comment, and that is located inside the members table. I have a foreign key reference between these two tables.

However, the code isn't working, anyone can find out why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL is not formed correctly. Your `WHERE` clause needs to come after all of your joins, just before your `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT community.comment, members.Name, members.Picture
FROM community 
INNER JOIN members
ON community.userid=members.Memberid
WHERE community.ideaid=1
GROUP BY community.userid
```